# Computing daily occurrence for non-numeric column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe (hourly time stamp index):

```
                      relative_humidity                 condition   fid
2017-08-02 10:00:00               0.49  Chance of a Thunderstorm     1
2017-08-02 11:00:00               0.50  Chance of a Thunderstorm     1
2017-08-02 12:00:00               0.54             Partly Cloudy     1
2017-08-02 13:00:00               0.58             Partly Cloudy     2
2017-08-02 14:00:00               0.68             Partly Cloudy     2
```

How can I compute the condition which occurs most often daily and put that in a dataframe with the date as index. Also need to separate by `fid`?

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['fid', pd.Grouper(freq='D')])['condition']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `index[0]`, because data are sorted and first value is top:

```
d = {'level_1':'date'}
df1 = df.groupby(['fid', pd.Grouper(freq='D')])['condition'] \
       .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index().rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
   fid       date                 condition
0    1 2017-08-02  Chance of a Thunderstorm
1    2 2017-08-02             Partly Cloudy
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, I want output dataframe to have a daily time-stamp as index. Your answer gives a multi-index as result

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['fid',pd.Grouper(freq='D'),'condition']).size().groupby(level=[0,1]).head(1)
```

Output:

```
fid              condition               
1    2017-08-02  Chance of a Thunderstorm    2
2    2017-08-02  Partly Cloudy               2
dtype: int64
```